# short story: Abandoned city is still being repaired by robots. Civilization thinks the technology on their planet is part of the natural world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have been searching all my anthologies as well as the internet for a while.

My memory is faint on this but I'll try to reproduce as much of it as I can remember.

> A traveler comes across a planet with an abandoned city. There are robots roaming around repairing the city but there are no people occupying the city. Its as if the robots were meant to run indefinitely and the inhabitants have long been gone but the robots carry on.
>
> The traveler comes across a transportation vehicle of sorts. Similar to what I imagine was a mix between an elevator and a hovercraft. If I recall, the vehicle seemed to be carved out of stone with no or very few control mechanisms. the vehicle lifts off and carries the traveler to another part of the world. Once hovering over this new part of the world, inhabitants start to gather around and look up at the vehicle. It is at this point the traveler is uneasy and not sure what will happen next. the vehicle starts to bring him to the ground.
>
> That's unfortunately about all I can remember.

I am interested in finding the source of this story because I would love to explore further the concept of a civilization who has lost the knowledge of where their technology originates. In this story the inhabitants viewed the technology as just a part of their natural environment. As taken for granted as a tree, mountain, or river. Any reference to stories in this vein would be appreciated even if its not the one I remember.

The story is NOT:

"Forgetfulness", "The Machine Stops" or, "Against the Fall of Night"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any idea when you might have read this?  Do you recall any other stories you read around the same time?

Comment: I believe I read this at a minimum 2 years ago. Most of the stories I was reading at the time were out of pulp from the 30's -50's. I was also reading the science fiction hall of fame vol 1 at that time but have confirmed it is not in that anthology.

Comment: How do you know the inhabitants viewed the technology as part of the natural world? In the part of the story you recount, there is no interaction with the inhabitants.

Comment: Its just an aspect of the story I can remember but I don't recall the supporting content. I definitely read more after the vehicle touches ground near the inhabitants and there is some level of interaction between the traveler and the inhabitants. but I can't recall anything about those interactions.

Comment: I don't know why I immediately thought of the novel _[Daybreak: 2250 A.D.](https://www.tor.com/2018/01/22/after-the-apocalypse-andre-nortons-daybreak-2250-a-d/)_, aka _Star Man's Son_, by Andre Norton, because I read it a looooooong time ago and don't even remember if the scene you described is in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this was 2 years ago, but I THINK you're thinking about *Twilight* by Campbell.

(I actually only found this post because I was trying to remember what Against the Fall of Night was called)

From *Twilight*:

> The entire lower block of the city was given over to the machines. Thousands. But most of them seemed idle, or, at most, running under light load. I recognized a telephone apparatus, and not a single signal came through. There was no life in the city. Yet when I pressed a little stud beside the screen on one side of the room, the machine began working instantly. It was ready. Only no one needed it any more. The men knew how to die, and be dead, but the machines didn’t.
>
> Then high above, something appeared, and from the city beneath me, from a center section, three small spheres rose. They, like the freight ship, had no visible driving mechanisms. The point in the sky above, like a black star in a blue space, had grown to a moon. The three spheres met it high above. Then together they descended and lowered into the center of the city, where I could not see them.
>
> It didn’t descend when it reached San Frisco. It simply hung in the air and sounded a soft musical hum. Twice. Then it waited. I waited, too, and looked down. There were people here. I saw the humans of that age for the first time. They were little men – bewildered – dwarfed, with heads disproportionately large. But not extremely so.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please [edit] the quote into your answer.

Comment: I bet "Twilight" is the story the OP has in mind. It should be pointed out, though, that the planet in "Twilight" is far-future Earth and the traveler is a time-traveler. The OP can read "Twilight" at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/astounding_v14n03_1934-11_1.1/page/n45/mode/2up) to see how well it matches his recollection. It was reprinted in, among many other places, [*The Science Fiction Hall of Fame*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?653221).

Comment: Thank You! I thought I had checked "The Science Fiction Hall of Fame" over for this story. I clearly missed it!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a little bit like the Arthur C. Clarke story "[*Against the Fall of Night*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Against_the_Fall_of_Night)" - there's a technologically regressed society living in an advanced automatically maintained city and a high tech transport system.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It bothers me that I am so unsure about where I read the one I'm looking for. Unfortunately it is not "Against the Fall of Night" although I am definitely going to add this one to my reading list.